# Compile binary for older GLIBC?

Tags: compiling, glibc

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 Virtualbox instance that I can use to build an open source project (Grafana) that will later need to run on a Red Hat 4 box. When I run the executable I get a

```
/lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found
```

Given that glibc is backwards compatible, is it possible to force the compiling OS to compile in a manner that would allow the executable to run on an older glibc? Or would I need to create another VM with the same version of glibc as the OS that will later run the project?

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856438/how-can-i-link-to-a-specific-glibc-version